# Basic map question

Tags: functions

From Basic Algebra I by Jacobson:

Let $S=\{1,2,...\}$. Give an example of two maps $\alpha , \beta$ of $S$ into $S$ such that $\alpha\beta=1_s$ but $\beta\alpha \ne 1_s$. Can this happen if $\alpha$ is bijective?

This must be really obvious but I can't think of an example.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the following example:

$$\beta(s) =2s$$ 
$$ \alpha(s) = \begin{cases} 
      \frac{s}{2} & \textrm{ if $s$ is even} \\
      1& \textrm{ if $s$ is odd} \\
   \end{cases} .$$

Comment: That makes sense. Perhaps I was thinking too finitely. Can you solve this for a finite subset of the natural numbers?